# How to use file upload input with Formik

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I'm trying to make file upload input (image) with file extension limitation (.jpg, .png)

I use formik and this component `import { SimpleFileUpload } from 'formik-material-ui'`

Everything works fine, but `accept` props not working.
I tried to make it like that:

```
  <Field
    name="file"
    type="file"
    component={SimpleFileUpload}
    accept={acceptFileType}
    inputProps={
      accept: acceptFileType
    }
  />

// accept={}, inputProps={accept} - both not works
```

I can select file, but without limitation I mean I can choose .mp4 file